# WPF Приложение под MAC OS

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, ios, visual-studio

Есть приложение на WPF, которое отлично работает под `Windows` но требуется также портировать под MAC OS. Возможно ли такое средствами Visual Studio ? Обязательно ли нужен MAC ? Какие в принципе есть инструменты (платные, бесплатные - неважно) для Компиляции C# под MAC OS ?

Comment: xamarin. насчёт Mac не знаю, но под IOS работает

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону Mono http://www.mono-project.com/ или .Net Core https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd

Comment: Ни Mono, ни основывающийся на нём Xamarin вам вряд ли помогут, т.к. первый не поддерживает WPF даже частично. Есть частичная поддержка WinForm, а вот WPF они вроде даже не пытаются портировать, ибо слишком много зависимостей с Windows.

Comment: WPF не портируется никуда, это технология только под Windows. Под телефоны, возможно, подошёл бы Xamarin Forms, который имеет общие элементы. А так — за разработку версии под Мак просите в полтора раза больше денег (и времени), и пишите с нуля.

Comment: Если ваше приложение разделено правильно на слои (модель, VM, View), то вы можете перенести модель практически как есть на Mono, VM, вероятно, тоже, а вот UI придётся писать заново и с нуля. Если у вас модельная логика в OnClick — работы, соответственно, больше.

Comment: @VladD а нельзя как то контроллы для WPF перестроить под WinForms?

Comment: @Сергей: Не так просто. Во-первых, WPF намного сложнее, чем WinForms, а во-вторых, я не уверен, пойдёт ли WinForms под Мак.

Comment: @VladD Разве WinForms не потдерживается в mac в .net core ?

Comment: @Сергей: Хм, не уверен. Вроде бы [поддерживается UWP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/#workloads), которое почти как WPF по идее.

Comment: @VladD Как бы вы поступили ? Стоит смотреть в сторону UWP ?

Comment: @Сергей: Написал бы хэлловорлд на UWP, попробовал бы скомпилировать его под Мак и запустить, оценил бы, работает или нет.

Comment: @VladD хеловорд написал пока только на консольке. ищу как в VS на мак установить upw проект или хотябы winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже отметили в комментариях, полностью WPF или Windows Forms для macOS не поддерживается ни в .NET Core, ни в Mono.

На вашем месте я бы либо написал с нуля под macOS нативное приложение, либо посмотрел бы в сторону переписывания исходного приложения под кроссплатформенные технологии (в случае с .NET Xamarin представляется единственным выбором).

Comment: Макбук обязателен ? Элементы WPF USerrControl можно как то портировать ?

Comment: Да, необходим компьютер с macOS не ниже 10.10 с Xcode 7 и выше. Напрямую использовать контролы из WPF нельзя, придется переписывать (скорее, перерисовывать через Interface Builder). Это относится к обоим предложенным мной вариантам.

Answer (score 0):

Вдруг кто-то сюда забредёт.

Есть замечательный проект [AvaloniaUI](https://avaloniaui.net/blog/2018-10-09-avalonia-native-osx), это не WPF, но идеологически - наследник. Соответственно, портировать на этот фреймворк должно быть проще, чем писать нативное с нуля.

**Но!** Проект наконец вошел в стадию релиза, как я понимаю, менее года назад. Плюс, не известно, какие трудности разработчик встретит, по сравнению с нативной разработкой. Так что в продакшене использовать на свой страх и риск.